# python: how to track new directory creation in a directory with subdirectories

Tags: python, windows, directory

I want to write a python script (and run it 24/7 on windows 7 in the background) which is checking if a new directory is created in c:\Data\ or in subdirectories of c:\Data (e.g. c:\Data\1\2\3\ or c:\Data\1\test\2)

What is the most performant way (on windows 7) to track directory creation?

Comment: Some googling got me this: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

Comment: SOLVED. Thanks forivall! The "ReadDirectoryChanges" example is what I need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) to hook into the windows api. Then use one of the [change notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get changes as they occur. This will be painful in python, but it will be the most performant way to monitor a directory for changes. Note that this only works on local file systems, not network file systems.

Your only other option is to check and sleep, which is full of fun little surprises and edge cases. My favorite is that windows writes the file pointers *before it writes file contents*. Given enough time, you will "find" a file before it exists, and all your code will fail. And you cannot wait for a fixed time after you see it, since it might not be done writing.

Network writes of several hundred meg files anyone?

Comment: Sounds like the best and hardest way as well

Comment: @JohnBrown I wrote a python program that monitored directories across a network share, and so I couldn't use change notifications. Experience dictates that I tell you if at all possible do not use sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick scan tool that scans changes for every 10 seconds:

```
>>> import os
>>> from time import sleep
>>> def build_dir_tree(base):
    all_dirs = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base):
        for dir_ in dirs:
            all_dirs.append(os.path.join(root, dir_))
    return all_dirs

>>> base = r'E:\CFM\IT\Dev\Python\test'
>>> old_dirs = build_dir_tree(base)
>>> while True:
    new_dirs = build_dir_tree(base)
    removed = [d for d in old_dirs if d not in new_dirs]
    added = [d for d in new_dirs if d not in old_dirs]
    print 'Added :', added, '- Removed:', removed
    old_dirs = new_dirs
    sleep(10)


Added : [] - Removed: []
Added : ['E:\\CFM\\IT\\Dev\\Python\\test\\hep'] - Removed: []
Added : [] - Removed: []
Added : ['E:\\CFM\\IT\\Dev\\Python\\test\\hop\\hap'] - Removed: []
Added : [] - Removed: ['E:\\CFM\\IT\\Dev\\Python\\test\\hep']
```

You just have to adapt it with your time step, time display etc.

Comment: Unfortunately this is very slow. It would be cool if the directory creation could be tracked as fast as possible e.g. by using some kind of windows notifier